# Dirac delta-based, cone-shaped probability density function, line segments

Tags: analysis, probability-distributions

Is it possible to describe a cone-shaped distribution of line segments by using a Dirac delta probability density function (pdf) in the spherical coordinate system shifted to any theta angle other than pi/2? If, then how would the Dirac delta pdf look like?
Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94308/discussion-on-question-by-euclides-dirac-delta-based-cone-shaped-probability-de).